# Why can't I specific the default selected radiobutton?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

I am making a simple GUI using Python's tkinter module, and I'm having a lot of trouble with radiobuttons. I wish to have the first selected by default, but the other two are selected at the start. Additionally, when I just pass the cursor over the window, the first one becomes checked (I do not click) so all 3 show as selected. My code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class openGUI(object):
    def __init__(self):

        # title of window 
        window.title("DUNE LArTPC Simulator")

        # label for choices
        self.question = tk.Label(window, text = "Do you want to create new or analyse existing data?")
        self.question.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        
        # buttons corresponding to choices
        self.createBtn = tk.Button(window, text = "Create", command = self.createData)
        self.analyseBtn = tk.Button(window, text = "Analyse", command = self.analyseData)
        self.createBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.analyseBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    def analyseData(self):
        """
        Not implemented yet.
        """

        pass 

    def createData(self):
        
        # edit window to display new widgets (irritating to have lots of windows open!)
        window.title("Select variable")
        self.question.destroy()
        self.createBtn.destroy()
        self.analyseBtn.destroy()

        # text in window 
        variableQ = tk.Label(window, text = "Please select Independent variable for dataset:")
        variableQ.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

        # radioselect variable  
        selection = tk.StringVar()
        selection.set("lifetime")

        # radioselect buttons 
        lifetimeBtn = tk.Radiobutton(window, variable = selection, value = "lifetime", text = "Lifetime")
        elecNoiseBtn = tk.Radiobutton(window, variable = selection, value = "electronic", text = "Electronic Noise")
        radioactivityBtn = tk.Radiobutton(window, variable = selection, value = "radioactive", text = "Radioactivity")
        lifetimeBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        elecNoiseBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        radioactivityBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

# create window 
window = tk.Tk()

# create class object with methods to populate 
# window with widgets 
initWin = openGUI()

# enter mainloop 
window.mainloop()
```

Running the above gives me:

[image]

I have tried using `lifetimeBtn.select()` method instead of setting the StringVar(), but this does not seem to work either. What have I missed?

EDIT: added rest of code to show how I am using class and functions to manipulate the window.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It appears that some or all of this code belongs in a class and/or function, but there is no class or method definition.

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: Your code works fine.  But if i change all `variable = selection` to `variable = 'selection'`, then I get the same issue.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've added the rest of my code, showing the class and function structure I'm using to make the GUI. Are you able to see my error now?! Thanks!

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks for trying it. I've added the rest of my code showing the class I'm using - are you able to see the error now?

Comment: @acw1668 What about now with the additional code I posted? :)

Comment: It is because `selection` is garbage collected.  Change `selection` to `self.selection`.

Comment: @acw1668 genius! That did the trick. I overlooked that - thanks! If you make that an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `selection` is a local variable inside `createData()` function and it will be garbage collected after function completes.

Change `selection` to instance variable `self.selection`.